# Building an "eventually dense" and divergent sequence in $\Bbb Q_{>0}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Call $R=\{R_n\}_n$ a sequence such that:

$(i)\;\;\;R_n\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$

$(ii)\;\;$strictly increasing

$(iii)\;\;R_n\to+\infty$.

Now consider a sequence of such sequences $R^{(j)}=\{R_n^{(j)}\}_n$ such that

$\bullet\;\;\;R^{(j)}\subset R^{(j+1)}\;\;\forall j\in\Bbb N$

$\bullet\;\;\;\bigcup_jR^{(j)}=\Bbb Q_{>0}\;$.

I want to construct (another!) sequence $T=\{T_n\}_n$ verifying $(i),(ii)$ and $(iii)$ such that $T_j$ is the smallest element of $R^{(j)}$ greater than $T_{j-1}$.

Clearly we can take $T_1:=R_1^{(1)}$ and inductively define $T_n$ to be the smallest element in $R^{(n)}$ strictly bigger than $T_{n-1}$.

The problem is to achieve $(iii)$.

Does exists a choice of $R^{(j)}$ and $T$ which allows this? Or does it always happen that for any choice of them $T$ turns out to be bounded?

Is the following a solution?

Define $R^{(1)}=\Bbb N$ and

$$
R^{(j+1)}=\left\{R_n^{(j)},\frac{R_n^{(j)}+R_{n+1}^{(j)}}2,R_n^{(j)}+\frac1{j+1},\;n\in\Bbb N\right\}
$$
relabelled as $\{R_n^{(j+1)}\}_n$ such that they are increasing.

Define then
$$
T_1=R_1^{(1)}
$$
$$
T_2=R_1^{(1)}+\frac12=R^{(2)}_{k_2},\;\; \exists k_2
$$
then
$$
T_3=R_{k_2}^{(2)}+\frac13=R_{k_3}^{(3)}\;\;\exists k_3
$$
and so on. In this way
$$
T_n=1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n\to+\infty.
$$
but I can't really see if $T_j$ is actually the smallest element of $R^{(j)}$ greater than $T_{j-1}$

Comment: In this world of haters it seems mathematicians are well integrated. It would be nice to insert a mandatory explanation for every downvote.

Answer (score 1):

What you have chosen may not tend to $\infty$. Instead, define $T_n$ to be the smallest element in $R^{(n)}$ strictly bigger than $\max(T_{n-1}, n)$.